# How to align "pages of floats" to the top margin?

Tags: latex

If I include `[p]` in the placement specifier of a `\begin{figure}` environment, figure floats may be placed on a dedicated page. However, at least in the "book" document class, floats are centered vertically on those pages.

How do I force all "pages-o-floats" to be aligned to the top margin (just like normal text pages)?

Comment: It's curious how a huge proportion of questions here are about HTML/CSS, and when a question about a Turing-complete language is actually asked, some suggest it should be closed as "not programming related". Good luck with your question.

Comment: Pascal, I didn't post before checking where LaTeX questions belong. I wanted to post to the most appropriate site of the Stack Overflow "family", and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/ indicates that it means right here. The answer to a simple LaTeX question might involve heavy macro programming after all.

Comment: Pascal is not criticizing you, rather the person or people who *persistently* cast those votes despite being pointed at the meta discussions on the topic over and over again. But fear not; this question will stay on SO, and end in an open state. Now, if only I had the answer to you question...

Comment: @dmckee: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Seeing the close vote, I read Pascal's note like he had voted it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe your answer is in the [UK TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=vertposfp):

> \@fptop defines the distance from the top of the page to the top of the first float

The simple fix is to reset \@fptop in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

However, you might find that this is a bit too high, so you might want something like 5pt instead. (Anyway, the FAQ entry is well worth reading; it explains in more depth what's going on than I am here.)

Answer (score 0):

can you not use the `[t]` specifier instead of `[p]`?

Comment: I believe `[t]` is for positioning floats at the top of text pages.